# C# fails to catch error in opening a database connection?

Tags: c#, database, ms-access

I have written a function in my windows forms application that will return true or false based on the success in opening a connection to a database however my try catch block fails to catch the exception that is thrown.

```
    private bool TestConnect()
    {
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            return true;
        }
        catch (OleDbException e) { return false; }
    }
```

Error thrown:

```
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException
```

Please help, I can not for the life of me figure this one out!

Comment: Mmmm, please add complete code of connection

Comment: Please show the line of code that's throwing the exception and the complete exception message

Comment: Try catching exception with "Exception" to make sure that it's not other exception

Comment: Did you debug the code? How do you know the exception is thrown? Is the same above code which you expect to throw the exception or some other code?

Comment: Are you trying to catch the exception from where the method is being called?

Comment: I have tried to replace it with Exception ex and I know its throwing an error because I changed my connection string so that it could not connect. I need this method to determine if the path to my database is valid

Comment: And yes I am indeed trying to catch the exception where the method is called.

Comment: In some cases just opening the connection is not enough.   This is one area where is depends on the DB/Provider and I cant recall the situation for Access/OleDB for certain but it sounds like it wont throw until you try to *use* the connection

Comment: `TestConnect` method handles the exception inside itself and it returns false if it catches `OleDbException`. So you won't get exception where you are calling the method. The code which calls this method will get true or false based on if the connection is success or exception.do you mind sharing the code which calls this method and what is your expectations there?

Answer (score -1):

I figured it out, I needed to alert VS that I wanted to Except this error

Comment: You are misunderstanding something if you are talking about VisualStudios debugger Exception window. That’s not about setting if an exception should be catched (exceptions will always be catched in the appropriate catch block), but it’s about if the _debugger_ should break when encountering the exception. It will not affect your program flow.

Comment: Surely there is a miss by a mile between what's your understanding and what you are explaining here. And what you just said about visual studio is nowhere near...